# Switch based url redirection

Tags: javascript

I'm having a problem get this piece of code to work:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#ButtonAluguel').click(function(){
     { 
       var id = $(this).attr('name');
       var str = "";
       $("option:selected").each(function () {
         switch(id=='Trololo'){
         case true:
            var option = $(this);
            str += '?tid_1[]='+ option.attr('value');
            break;   
        case false:
            var option = $(this);
            str += '?tid[]='+ option.attr('value');break;
       }
      });
      window.location = "localhost/aluguel"+ str;
    }});
  });
```

I need it to keep adding stuff to "str" based on the name of a multiple select, identified above as id. Long story short, if the name of the select is "Trololo", id adds tid_1[], if not, it adds tid[] to the str. Any help is appreciated.

Edit:
The multiple select code is as follows(Forgot to put it in the first place, the question doesn't make much sense without it)

```
     <form >
<select class="SelectTipoAluguel"  multiple="true" data-placeholder="Tipo de Imóvel" style="width:200px;">
        <option value="1">Aasdasdasd</option>
        <option value="2">B</option>
        <option value="3">C</option>
        <option value="4">D</option>
</select>
<select name="Trololo" class="SelectBairroAluguel" id="trololo" multiple="true" data-placeholder="Bairro" style="width:200px;">
        <option value="1">Aadasd</option>
        <option value="2">Basda</option>
        <option value="3">Casda</option>
        <option value="4">Dasda</option>
</select>
<input class="ButtonSubmitHome" id="ButtonAluguel" value="Pesquisar" >
  </form>
```

To explain it more clearly, the user must fill the form and choose between the options, so when he clicks the `"ButtonAluguel"`, every option from the select `"SelectTipoAluguel"` is added to the URL as `tid[]` and the ones from `"SelectBairroAluguel"` is added to the URL as `tid_1[]`

Comment: have you just seriously done a `switch(boolean)` to have two cases with `true` and `false`? what happend to `if`?

Comment: also, what else should it it attach to the `str`? or do you mean that the `option.attr('value')` is not appended? have you tried console logging it to see what's in it? maybe it's really empty

Comment: Have also tried with if but it was giving me the same return. Everything in the code works just fine, only problem is the part to alternate between tid_1[] and tid[].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code edited to reference updated question and OP's comments.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var id;
  var str = "";
  $('#ButtonAluguel').click(function() {
    var option = [];
    $('select option:selected').each(function(i, selected) {
      id = $(this).parent().attr('name');
      option[i] = $(selected).val();
      if (id == 'Trololo') {
        str += '?tid_1[]=' + option[i];
      } else {
        str += '?tid[]=' + option[i];
      }
    });
    var url = "localhost/aluguel" + str;
    console.log(url);
    //window.location = "localhost/aluguel" + str;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="SelectTipoAluguel" multiple="true" data-placeholder="Tipo de Imóvel" style="width:200px;">
  <option value="1">Aasdasdasd</option>
  <option value="2">B</option>
  <option value="3">C</option>
  <option value="4">D</option>
</select>
<select name="Trololo" class="SelectBairroAluguel" id="trololo" multiple="true" data-placeholder="Bairro" style="width:200px;">
  <option value="1">Aadasd</option>
  <option value="2">Basda</option>
  <option value="3">Casda</option>
  <option value="4">Dasda</option>
</select>
<input class="ButtonSubmitHome" id="ButtonAluguel" value="Pesquisar">
```

Comment: Your answer clarified me some things, I've edited my original post to make things clearer

Comment: Updated.  Let me know if that is what you meant.  Note the change of `?` to `&` in the second key/value in the query string.

Comment: That is almost perfect, only problem is that it conflicts with other form in the same page and also, it's getting the values separeted by a comma, when i need it to really duplicate the ?tid, so if 1, 2 and 3 is selected, it needs to return ?tid[]=1?tid[]=2?tid[]=3 instead of tid[]=1,2,3.
Forgive me if I'm being a freeloader, but my head just refuses to fully understand javascript.

Comment: Think I follow now.  Updated.

Comment: If you have conflicts with other select elements, you'll need to give these a common class and use that as the selector.  At the moment, the code above just assumes there are no other select elements on the page.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I needed, thank you so very much.

Comment: Good.  Please mark the question as answered, so that others can find a solution if they have a similar problem.